# Api platform demo project installation problem

Tags: api-platform.com

I want to try the api-platform demo ([link](https://github.com/api-platform/demo)) but when running `docker-compose up -d` I get this:

```
Step 25/34 : RUN set -eux;  mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev;   composer dump-env prod;     composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd;  chmod +x bin/console; sync
 ---> Running in ce481c894af3
+ mkdir -p var/cache var/log
+ composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev
Generating optimized autoload files (authoritative)
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
Generated optimized autoload files (authoritative) containing 4186 classes
+ composer dump-env prod

                                                                                                      
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                  
  Please run "composer require symfony/dotenv" to load the ".env" files configuring the application.  
                                                                                                      

symfony:dump-env [--empty] [--] [<env>]

The command '/bin/sh -c set -eux;   mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev;   composer dump-env prod;     composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd;  chmod +x bin/console; sync' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Docker: version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5

Docker-compose: version 1.28.4, build cabd5cfb

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a pull request to fix it. just update the composer.lock file https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/pull/1826

Comment: That's works, many thanks! I'm sure the PR will get merged soon!